# Handling wildcard expansion with python subprocess call

Tags: python, subprocess, glob

I'm calling this function and using `%s*silent` to **read** files that have names with the following format: `name.number.silent.`

I get the name from `start_model.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]` so don't worry about it.

This is obviously **not** working because these commands are actually never passed to the shell. If I were to use glob, how can I modify my code to do what I'm doing below?

```
from subprocess import call

def fragment_score(rosetta_path, silent_input_and_score_output, start_model):
    call([rosetta_path,
          '-mode score', 
          '-in::file::silent', '%s/%s*silent' % (silent_input_and_score_output, start_model.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]),
          '-scorefile', '%s/scores1' % silent_input_and_score_output,
          '-n_matches', '50'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [the Python `glob` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) to generate a list of glob results, and splice it into your argument list at the same position where you would otherwise have a shell replacing a glob expression with the list of associated matches:

```
from subprocess import call
from glob import glob

def fragment_score(rosetta_path, silent_input_and_score_output, start_model):
    glob_exp = '%s/%s*silent' % (silent_input_and_score_output, start_model.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0])
    glob_results = glob(glob_exp)
    call([rosetta_path,
          '-mode score', 
          '-in::file::silent'
         ] + glob_results + [
          '-scorefile', '%s/scores1' % silent_input_and_score_output,
          '-n_matches', '50'])
```

In current Python 3.x, there's syntax that makes this a bit more natural:

```
    call([rosetta_path,
          '-mode score', 
          '-in::file::silent',
          *glob_results,
          '-scorefile', '%s/scores1' % silent_input_and_score_output,
          '-n_matches', '50'])
```

Comment: On a sufficiently recent Python 3, unpacking the `glob` results into the list with `*` could simplify things.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm actually using Python 3.5. This syntax "] + glob_results + [" doesn't look valid to me or my editor. What does it do? Would it work for 3.5?

Comment: Why doesn't it look valid? The `]` closes the prior list started with `]`, the `[` starts a new list, the `+`s add those lists together with the results of the `glob()` call. There's nothing unusual about it at all.

Comment: Thus, this is exactly the same syntax you're using with `[1,2,3] + [4,5,6] + [7,8,9]`, just where the `[4,5,6]` is what's returned by the `glob()` call.

Comment: ...that said, in Python 3.5, you could expand `*glob_results` into the list, using the same syntax as in `l=[4,5,6]; print([1,2,3,*l,7,8,9]` -- as @user2357112 pointed out earlier.